# typeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame

Eu estou tentando adicionar layers pra janela do meu jogo, então tentei usar sprite groups, mas tem esse erro que eu não entendo porque persiste:

> ```
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
> ```

Eu pesquisei e parece que acontece quando uma função e uma variável tem o mesmo nome, mas no meu código não existe nenhuma função ou variável com o mesmo nome.

```
sprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
green = (0, 255, 0)

class Block (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__ (self, color, width, height):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x/2
        self.rect.y = y/2
quadrado = Block(green, 50, 50)
sprite.add(quadrado)
```

Eu estava tentando importar uma imagem, mas deu esse problema e resumi pra rect.

Comment: Não tem como clocar no código um comentário indicando a linha onde que interpretador aponta o erro. E no caso da mensagem de erro ser mais verbosa anexar toa a mensagem.

Answer (score 1):

É na linha pygame.surface - esse é o nome do módulo - você deve usar pygame.Surface (com "S" maiúsculo) - para criar uma instância da classe Surface.

Isso é comum em alguns projetos de médio para grande porte em Python: 
os nomes dos módulos e subpacotes do projeto - que são os arquivos ".py" que o projeto usa internamente, aparecem para quem vai usar o projeto - mesmo que seja um uso mais ou menos simples. Ao mesmo tempo, o projeto precisa deixar disponível as classes e funções criadas nesses módulos.

É o caso da classe `Surface` - que pode ser usada diretamente como  `pygame.Surface`  - mas o pygame também tem um arquivo `surface.py` onde (muito provavelmente) está definida a classe Surface mesmo, com o comando `class Surface...` .

Em um projeto meu, eu tenho um atributo `context` , uma classe `Context` e preciso definir tudo em um arquivo  - que chamei de `contexts.py` - então os usuários vão ver os 3 nomes.